# Xcode 7 without the simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, swift2

I wanted to know if it was possible to run an application-only console.

I make small application "test" without a GUI. So I lost a lot of time to launch my project to test my code because the simulator.

Is it possible to run a project only with the console, so I would like XCODE not run my app in the simulator. For cons, I would still like to show that my "print" in my console.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to develop iOS code, you need to either run it on the sim or on a device. If you just want to make a command line tool or write console code then make it Mac OS.

If you're not doing UI the underlying frameworks are largely identical.

That said, I have written test apps based on the "single view controller" template and then simply written code that runs in the app delegate, dumps results to the console, and then quits. It launches the simulator (or launches to a device) but so what.

Comment: okay, so if I understand, I can not? I must necessarily use the simulator?

Comment: Reread the first sentence of my answer. I can't be any clearer than that.